# Under Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), where do I put my free() statements?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, free, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

In cocoa, ARC frees you of having to worry about retain, release, autorelease, etc.  It also prohibits calling `[super dealloc]`.  A `-(void) dealloc` method is allowed, but I'm not sure if/when it's called.

I get how this is all great for objects, etc., but where do I put the `free()` that matches the `malloc()` I did in `-(id) init` ?

Example:

```
@implementation SomeObject

- (id) initWithSize: (Vertex3Di) theSize
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        size = theSize;
        filled = malloc(size.x * size.y * size.z);
        if (filled == nil)
        {
            //* TODO: handle error
            self = nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}


- (void) dealloc         // does this ever get called?  If so, at the normal time, like I expect?
{
    if (filled)
        free(filled);    // is this the right way to do this?
    // [super dealloc];  // This is certainly not allowed in ARC!
}
```

Comment: `free(0)` is a no-op, so `free(filled)` is a simpler way to write `if (filled) free(filled);`. (I see another poster wrote this below, but it's not in the accepted answer so I thought I'd leave it here, too.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right, you have to implement `dealloc` and call `free` inside of it. `dealloc` will be called when the object is deallocated as before ARC. Also, you can't call `[super dealloc];` as this will be done automatically.

Finally, note that you can use `NSData` to allocate the memory for `filled`:

```
self.filledData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:size.x * size.y * size.z];
self.filled = [self.filledData mutableBytes];
```

When you do this, you don't have to explicitly free the memory as it will be done automatically when the object and consequently `filledData` are deallocated.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you put it in `-dealloc` just like you do under MRR. The only difference with `-dealloc` is you must not call `[super dealloc]`. Other than that, it's exactly the same, and will get called when the object is fully released.

---

As an aside, `free()` will accept the `NULL` pointer and do nothing, so you don't actually need that conditional in `-dealloc`. You could just say

```
- (void)dealloc {
    free(filled);
}
```